# PostgreSQL: How to create concurrency-safe check for max aggregate value (e.g. sum, count etc.) limit?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, rdbms

First let's assume we are using PostgreSQL 16 with the default isolation level, i.e. Read Commited.
Then let's take the following "notes" table as a simple example:

| id | text | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lorem_ | 1 |
| 2 | ipsum_ | 1 |

Let's assume we want to restrict each user to have max 1000 characters of all his notes. What's the right way to implement this check for the concurrent environment?
After investigation, I see the following alternatives:

1. Using "Serializable" isolation level – thus we'll be able to implement this check in the concurrency-safe manner either on the application (code) level or on the DB level (e.g. with triggers)
2. Using BEFORE / AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE trigger – but this approach doesn't look to be concurrency safe if we use Read Commited isolation level. For example, when user is creating the new note, there may be other concurrent transaction in progress which has already inserted a new note (but to prevent dirty read other operations can't see this yet because the transaction is still in progress). Then the transaction can simply commit and we'll exceed the limit. Also as far as I understood since PostgreSQL executes all the operations implicitly using autocommit transactions, the situation described before is also possible even if we don't use transactions explicitly, but use simple concurrent INSERT / UPDATE operations instead (**is it true?**).
3. Using transaction with shared / exclusive lock on the **user** row before the check and INSERT / UPDATE is performed. Thus other concurrent transactions will be waiting for the running transaction to commit / rollback, and we'll be able to implement this check in the concurrency-safe manner either on the application (code) level or on the DB level (e.g. with triggers) (the same as in the p.1 of the list).

Do I understand everything right? Are there any better alternatives of implementation?

I checked my hypothesis in p.2 of the list, except of for the simple INSERT queries (autocommit transactions) because I don't know how to check it without proper load testing.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using the Serializable isolation level to enforce a character restriction on user notes in a concurrent PostgreSQL environment as it offers excellent consistency guarantees. Either at the application level or through database triggers, you can implement this limitation. As an alternative, utilising transactions with shared or exclusive locks on the user's row before checking and inserting/updating notes is another secure method. This ensures that concurrent transactions wait for the lock to be released. When adopting locking techniques, keep in mind that there could be performance effects because of more contention. Optimistic concurrency control is another strategy to investigate; it verifies constraints before committing a transaction and offers concurrency with less contention. Your particular needs will ultimately determine your option.

Hope this helps, do let me know if you need more help, I'll try to solve this issue along with you.